# How to remove the special characters from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below String value to be displayed in text area and i want to remove the first characters @@*n|n from the string .

The string is as follows : 
     **Symbol-001
     @@*n|nClaimant Name
     @@*n|nTransaction**

I have used the below code to deal with removing the special characters

```
var paramVal1 = parent.noteText; //paramVal1 will have the string now
var pattern = /[@@*n|n]/g;
var paramVal1 = paramVal1.replace(pattern,'');
document.getElementById("txtNoteArea").value = paramval1;//appending the refined string to text area
```

For the above used code am getting the out put string as below

**Symbol-001
|Claimat Name**  *//here 'n' is missing and i have an extra '|' character*
**|Transactio**    *//'n' is missing here too and an extra '|' character*

Kindly help to remove the characters @@*n|n without affecting the other values

Answer (score 1):

What your regex is saying is "remove any of the following characters: `@|*n`". Clearly this isn't what you want!

Try this instead: `/@@\*n\|n/g`

This says "remove the literal string `@@*n|n`". The backslashes remove the special meaning from `*` and `|`.

Comment: I have tried the above two patterns but still not able to get ...ideally starting with @@*n|n patterns is the starting of every line in the string when am using the above two patterns it is removing 'n' character from the string....

Answer (score -1):

You are using regular expression reserved chars in your pattern, you need to escape them
You can use this expression:

```
var pattern = /[\@\@\*n\|n]/g;
```

Comment: `*` has no meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score -1):

i think use this   /[@@*n\|n]/g  regEx

Comment: `|` has no meaning inside a character class.

Comment: oho sorry i forgot to remove []

Comment: `*` *does* have a meaning outside a character class.

Comment: u r rite need to escape * too

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace the first occurrence as you say on your question, you don't need to use regex. A simple string will do, as long as you escape the asterisk:

```
var str = "Symbol-001 @@*n|nClaimant Name @@*n|nTransaction";
var str2 = str.replace("@@\*n|n", ""); //output: "Symbol-001 Claimant Name @@*n|nTransaction"
```

If you want to replace all the occurrences, you can use regex, escaping all the characters that have a special meaning:

```
var str3 = str.replace(/\@\@\*n\|n/g, ""); //output: "Symbol-001 Claimant Name Transaction"
```

Have a look at this regex builder, might come in handy - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: So, something else might be wrong. See it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/667ck/